# How to get content to show up in WebDriver .get request?

Tags: java, google-chrome, browser, selenium, webdriver

I wanted to automate some processes on www.imgur.com, and I decided to use the Selenium WebDriver library for Java.  I have been able to get much of my code to work with one hitch: when I access imgur directly only a white screen shoes up and will not change upon refresh. Accessing the sign in page directly yields an SSL error.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\workspace\\Test\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.imgur.com/signin");
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
username.sendKeys("username");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
String pass = "password";
password.sendKeys(pass);
password.submit();
driver.get("http://www.imgur.com");
```

I have been able to work around this by using links google searches provide to imgur, but adding more features will require I be able to manage the URL directly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It'd be useful to see more code. It seems unlikely that this is the problem, but have you been using driver.get("http://www.imgur.com");? An alternative to get() would be driver.navigate().to("http://www.imgur.com");

Comment: I was able to get the basic code running in C#.  I suspect some sort of block of imgur is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

It's just `http://imgur.com/`, not `http://www.imgur.com`. That's why Google's links work, they are linking to the first one - a different url.

The `www` prefix is not required by any technical policy. Some choose to have urls both with and without the prefix point to the same server. Some choose to use only one or the other. It seems imgur is going without the prefix.

Here's a little more info on the `www` prefix:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#WWW_prefix

Comment: Thanks! Shame it was such an obvious thing giving me trouble.